# Symfony Unable to load the TwigRenderer runtime

Tags: php, symfony, twig-extension, symfony-3.4

I upgraded from Symfony 3. to 3.4.2. and i got this error on page bundle:

**Unable to load the "Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Form\TwigRenderer" runtime.**

I tried to upgrade the twig bundle to the latest version (at the time of writing this line) v2.4.4 but in vain.
any help please.

This is the error stack trace:

```
Twig_Error_Runtime:
Unable to load the "Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Form\TwigRenderer" runtime.

  at vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php:663
  at Twig_Environment->getRuntime('Symfony\\Bridge\\Twig\\Form\\TwigRenderer')
     (vendor/sonata-project/page-bundle/src/Controller/PageAdminController.php:104)
  at Sonata\PageBundle\Controller\PageAdminController->treeAction(object(Request))
     (vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:151)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), 1)
     (vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:68)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), 1, true)
     (vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php:202)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
     (web/app_dev.php:28)
```

Comment: seems to be a BC break, you may need to open this issue at https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/ to tell them about that

Comment: @hassan : Done --> https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/25714

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is fixed by upgrading sonata page bundle to 3.7.1